# Convert the following npm script to gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I have the following npm script i want to convert to gulp task

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "npm run build:sdk && node .",
    "posttest": "npm run lint && nsp check",
    "build:sdk": "./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk server/server.js ./client/src/app/shared/sdk"
  },
```

Now i want a gulp task to have the same functionality as npm start . but i am not able to club the tasks as it will run the npm run build:sdk and then node .

Here is what i have done so far .

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.run('sdk');
  gulp.run('server');
  gulp.watch(['./common/models/*.js'], function() {
    gulp.run('server');
  });
});

gulp.task('server', function() {
  if (node) node.kill();
  node = spawn('node', ['server/server.js'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
  node.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code === 8) {
      gulp.log('Error detected, waiting for changes...');
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('sdk', function() {
  spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk server/server.js ./client/src/app/shared/sdk');
});
```

**Stack trace**

```
Error: spawn ./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk server/server.js ./client/src/app/shared/sdk ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:538:3
```

Comment: Try passing arguments as an array: `spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js ./client/src/app/shared/sdk']);`

Comment: actually i need to run both these process one after another first sdk and then server

Comment: I'm saying that your `spawn` statement call is wrong. That is why you got `Error: spawn ./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk server/server.js ./client/src/app/shared/sdk ENOENT`. The arguments should be passed as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.  First,  You have pass arguments to spawned process as an array.

```
gulp.task('sdk', function() {
      spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q']);
});
```

Second, you are using `gulp.run('sdk');`, which is depricated. You must be seeing this in your console, when you fix above problem. For that you have to pass dependecies to your `default` task and also to the `gulp.watch()`

```
gulp.task('default', ['sdk', 'server'] , function() {
  gulp.watch(['./common/models/*.js'], ['server']);
});
```

[image]

**Complete Gulp File**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var {spawn} = require('child_process');

var node = null;

gulp.task('default', ['sdk', 'server'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['./common/models/*.js'], ['server']);
});

gulp.task('server', function() {
  if (node) node.kill();
  node = spawn('node', ['server/server.js'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
  node.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code === 8) {
      gulp.log('Error detected, waiting for changes...');
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('sdk', function() {
  spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q']);
});
```

Comment: actually i need to run both these process one after another first sdk and then server

Comment: Yes, they are running in the order as per requirement. Please see screenshot attached. Also I've attached full gulpfile in answer.

Comment: *address in use error* is comming because some other process is using your port number. Kill other process and start again.

Comment: the processing now are running but the sdk has no effect it is not creating the files it is supposed to ?

Comment: what kind of files your are expecting and what is it generating?

Comment: the problem is that the sdk commands prompts a change Y/n in the console i always need to give Y is there a way to do it that is the reason the files are not getting developed

Comment: add `-q` arguments at the end of `lb-sdk` command. Updated the answer.

Comment: Please see updated answer. And you can check the documentation of `lb-sdk` by typing `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk` in your terminal.