# The following gulp task is not working on windows but working on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, gulp

The gulp task

```
/* Run the npm script npm run buildLsdk using gulp */
gulp.task('sdk', function() {
  if (process.cwd() != basePath) {
    process.chdir('..');
    // console.log(process.cwd());
  }
  spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

I am getting the following stack trace but i cannot debug

```
Error: spawn ./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

I have all the necessary files in node modules too any help is really appreciated.

More reference on the File use above - https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/loopback-Angular-Starter/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Is the gulpfile relative path ```./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk``` valid?

Comment: yes gulp file is in the same step as the node modules , cd to that folder works

Comment: import path to your file then try resolve node_modules file with path.resolve function?

var path = require('path');
path.resolve(file)

Comment: Are you running this piped in a longer process? Can you try running this task alone and tell us if it's the same result?

Comment: @GMaiolo yup tried it standalone too same error as with piped tasks, strangly works fine on my linux machine

Comment: I'm not sure what's the value of the variable ```basePath```, but please give a try and change it to ```__dirname``` instead

Comment: okay let me c , base path is nothing but this `var basePath = __dirname;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because lb-sdk.cmd is the file you're supposed to run on windows. when I changed the command to the below the error goes away. Please note the windows style directory slashes are different from linux.

```
gulp.task('sdk', function() {
spawn(
  '.\\node_modules\\.bin\\lb-sdk.cmd',
  [
    '.\\server\\server.js',
    '.\\client\\src\\app\\shared\\sdk',
    '-q'
  ], {stdio: 'inherit'}
);
});
```

I found some more information,and I'm going to post a second answer I found (above one was accepted).

If you want to avoid changing directories in windows/linux you can use cross-spawn: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn

win-spawn (from the chat dialog) is not maintained anymore [per the github repo](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay-Unmaintained/win-spawn) . If you're interested in using it make the following changes:

1. npm install cross-spawn
2. npm install spawn-sync
3. npm install strongloop ([needs to be reinstalled per this link](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/issues/26))
4. change 'google chrome' in browser-sync task to chrome.exe [per this link](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/browser-sync-couldnt-open-browser/10936):
5. run gulp

Comment: i get this as a stacktrace `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Sounds like a path issue, try removing "./" . in the node_modules param. So, make it 'node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk.cmd' .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error

Comment: then it says node_modules is not a function i also feel the same , but i just cant get my head across windows

Comment: you wont believe i also ended up in the same question

Comment: At this point, I think it's some env/setup issue. I'm going to take another look tonight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162831/discussion-between-jonathan-chaplin-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: Windows directory slash is different than linux. I updated and it resolved the latest issue

Comment: @RahulSingh is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Great. After I found this solution, I actually found  a secondary solution using cross-spawn (cross platform compatible), I think you might like that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this similar answer, this will solve your issue:

[Convert the following npm script to gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788084/convert-the-following-npm-script-to-gulp-task?rq=1)

[How to automate the build from the following configuration using gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800822/how-to-automate-the-build-from-the-following-configuration-using-gulp)

And you can check the documentation of `lb-sdk` by typing `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk` in your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using `basePath` when passing `server/server.js` and `./client/src/app/shared/sdk`. Like for example:

```
spawn(
  './node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk',
  [
    basePath + '/server/server.js',
    basePath + '/client/src/app/shared/sdk',
    '-q'
  ], {stdio: 'inherit'}
);
```

Comment: Yup let me try , but i am already using the base path and it will refer or should refer from the same point i guess , but will give it a shot

Comment: Still the same error @Krasimir my hard luck, i just dnt get it whats worng why it works stand alone and not in a bundled task and in linux works well, Same `error` by the way